# star wars name generator code

Tags: java

i have to make a code that makes a star wars name generator and it asks for names but only takes certain letters from the name to come up with the star wars name, my program wont compile can anyone see what im doing wrong :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StarWarsName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
        firstname = input.nextLine();
        first = first.substring(0,3);

        System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");
        lastname = input.nextLine();
        last = last.substring(0,2);

        System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
        mothersname = input.nextLine();
        mother = mother.substring(0,2);

        System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
        cityname = input.nextLine();
        city = city.substring(0,3);

        StarWarsName = first +" "+ last +" "+ mother +" "+ city + " of " + last +" "+$
        System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + StarWarsName + "May the fo$
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the compile error occur?

Comment: what is `first`, what is `last` and what is `city` ? where do you instantiate those variables?

Comment: BEST QUESTION EVER! +1

Answer (score 2):

Starting with this line:

```
firstname = input.nextLine();
```

Hints:

1) Where is `firstname` declared?

2) Read the compilation error message!

3) When you ask someone else a question about a compilation error, you need to say what the compilation error was, and where it occurred.

And consider this line:

```
StarWarsName = first +" "+ last +" "+ mother +" "+ city + " of " + last +" "+$
```

4) The `$` at the end is not valid Java.  It looks like a copy and paste error.  If a line in a Java program is too long to fit on your (anticipated) display device, it is *common practice* to split it; e.g.

```
    StarWarsName = first +" "+ last +" "+ mother +" "+ city + " of " + 
            last + " " + and + " " + the + " " + rest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several undeclared variables, eg `firstname`. I think there are also some logical mistakes, as you do not use `firstname` and others.